# Transition- Convert Ubuntu 16.04 to Lubuntu 18.10(without internet)

Tags: lubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 (it also says LTS(if that's relevant)) from a bootable USB which my brother gave to me. He had both 16 and 18 but said that my laptop may not be able to run the 18th. Now, I want a better version, so he said I must convert it into Lubuntu. How to do that?

Keep in mind that I have a fully installed Ubuntu 16, with an Intel Atom chip ie. 1.66GHz x 2. I want to install the latest version of Lubuntu (18.10 at this time).

***But, I can't spare to download lubuntu due to mobile data cap, so is there a way through which I could convert my Ubuntu into Lubuntu (without internet)?***

I'm specifically looking for procedures and commands. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  There is no Ubuntu 16, or Ubuntu 18.  Ubuntu releases are in format yy.mm , so for 2016 there is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (2016-April release) & Ubuntu 16.10 (2016-October release).  16.10 is EOL (end-of-life) thus off-topic here, so please clarify your version.  I have an old eeepc (atom n270, 1gb ram) that runs lubuntu fine, but I'd not run Ubuntu (gnome or unity) on it.

Comment: I think so you can do it via `lubuntu` task package but that requires almost 400mb - 1Gb internet `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop^`

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to transition from Ubuntu 16.04 to Lubuntu 18.04 is to back up everything (documents, pictures, and so forth) you want to keep and do a clean install.  This will remove all the Gnome components that were installed for the desktop in 16.04, as well as other packages that might also contribute to bogging down your system, and replace them with the "lightweight" Lubuntu components of the new version -- and do it with a minimum of fuss.

Once you have Lubuntu 18.04 installed, you can easily install other software you need that didn't come in the Lubuntu installer -- you'll have access to all the same repositories you did from Ubuntu 16.04 (except newer versions of almost everything).

Comment: A clean install is installing "new", as if you didn't already have Ubuntu on the system.  That's why I recommended backing up everything you want to keep -- the installer will delete everything off the hard disk (or partitions you choose to use) and replace it all with a fresh installation of Lubuntu 18.04 and empty space to store your data and install additional programs.

Comment: Got access to another computer?  One at a library, for instance?  Just put the .iso file on a USB stick, then transfer it to your netbook and use a CD burner app to put it back on the USB in bootable form, and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless

> you get a friend to create a live USB of Lubuntu

Also as in [Zeiss Ikon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1091478/707756)  you need to back up and do a clean install to avoid headaches